# ROS installation on raspberry 3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i want to install ROS indigo or jade desktop full on my raspberry pi 3 but i can't although i follow all tutorial.
is there any one has managed to install it with rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236608/ros-installation-on-raspberry-3/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-06-10**:
I've installed ROS indigo on a raspberry pi 1 b+ about a year ago. At one point I had a crash, but after a second run it worked surprisingly.

**Comment by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) on 2016-06-10**:
I used [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) tutorial, but I only installed ROS-Comm not desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I did succeed installing ROS indigo Desktop version on my raspberry by following [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi), but I didn't followed exactly all the steps because I faced many problems.

First of all, I am not sure if what I did is the perfect way to install it but it works for the moment and I am not facing any major problem with ROS on my raspberry pi.

Secondly, I did it with a raspberry pi 3 with raspbian jessie installed with NOOBS in a 16Gb microSD card.

So first, modify the size of the swap space (you will normally don't need to do it after). So I modified it from 100M to 3,0G. To do so, I opened the dphys-swapfile with a text editor (leafpad for example) and modified it.

```
$ sudo leafpad /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

and modified the line **CONF_SWAPSIZE=100** with **CONF_SWAPSIZE=3000**.

I saved, reboot, and kept following the tutorial until the installation of the liburdfom-dev library. After changing the name and pressing enter (as asked in the tutorial), it didn't installed it. I kept following the tutorial and tried to install the libcollada-dev.

After changing the name, it started to compile and put an error (related to liburdfom-dev). So I restarted the tutorial part of liburdfom-dev and after changing the name (again) and pressing enter, it compiled (didn't understand why).

I restarted the libcollada-dev part and it finally compiled.

I then had to patch the collada-urdf, what I did by reading one of [theses answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/230076/ros-on-raspberry-3/?answer=233636#post-id-233636). So I downloaded [it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-embedded/26XlDtZhyNs/OexZAx6BCBcJ), saved as **fix.patch** in **~/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_urdf/src** and lanched the following command line :

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_urdf/src
$ patch < fix.patch
```

I then followed the tutorial until the 3.3 Building the catkin workspace section.

I also had a few mysterious errors. I don't know f it's because I didn't do well for the first steps but here is what I have done.

My first error concerned the urdfdom-config.cmake file line 15, it put an error about the urdf_sensor library.
So I opened the urdfdom-config.cmake file :

```
$ sudo leafpad /usr/local/lib/urdfdom/cmake/urdfdom-config.cmake
```

and changed the line 8 **foreach(lib urdfdom_sensor;urdfdom_model_state;urdf_model;urdf_world)** by **foreach(lib urdfdom_sensor;urdfdom_model_state;urdf_model;urdf_world)** (I actually just changed the order of the arguments state_model with sensor). Save and keep going (do not abandon).

Again :

```
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

You will normally get an error with rviz.

Based on  [this tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/), so you will have to open **mesh_loader.cpp**. to do so :

```
 $ sudo leafpad ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/mesh_loader.cpp
```

copy :

```
#ifdef __arm__                 // fix for ARM build
#include <strings.h>
bool Assimp::IOSystem::ComparePaths(const char *p1, const char *p2) const
{
    return !::strcasecmp(p1, p2);
}
#endif
```

at the end of the includes part.

Finally again :

```
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

It will take some hours.

If you face problems in the last part, (Adding release packages), it could be because the are some missing libraries, for example, if usb.h is missing, type :

```
$ sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

PS : During the installation, the raspberry pi may seems to freeze but not, it's the RAM and the swap memory wich are beeing used. You can check the memory used by keeping a terminal open and typing (whenever you want):

```
$ free -h
```

You will see that when it freezes, the system starts using the swap memory. At the end of the installation, it could be possible to modify the swapfile as before to avoid problems, but I dont know if ROS can work with the default RAM of the raspberry pi 3.

I hope it will help someone. Do not hesitate, I may have forgotten some details.

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [fab](https://answers.ros.org/users/27121/fab/) with karma: 36 on 2016-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-13**:
thank you, i install it with rviz. but i can't after install any package with apt-get, i receive unable to locate package.
do you have any idea to resolve this?

**Comment by [fab](https://answers.ros.org/users/27121/fab/) on 2016-06-17**:
hi, it's maybe because it's the wrong package name. Can you put the name of the missing library ?